# Xml Parsing (WSDL format) not parse the data some times?

Tags: iphone, ios4, soap, xml-parsing

I am using Soap Web services and get response in XML and that Response i am store in NSMutableData and than i perform XML parsing i am using NSXMLParser. my problem is that some times it is works and some times not i can't determine what is the problem so anybody can help me to out of this problem.
I am using this code-

```
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://MYLINK......." forHTTPHeaderField:@"MY_action"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if(theConnection)
    {
        webData_msg = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
```

and getting also response in-

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData_msg appendData:data];  
}
```

but after getting response parse the xml here-

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if( xmlParser_msg)
    {
        [xmlParser_msg release];
        xmlParser_msg=nil;
    }
    xmlParser_msg = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData_msg];
    [xmlParser_msg setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParser_msg setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [xmlParser_msg parse];

    [connection release];
    [webData_msg release];
}
```

than problem arise here, some times NSXMLParserDelegate methods call some times not call.
What is going wrong here? please help and sorry for any mistake in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was getting HTML response through web service  so  xml purser hangs on that.
It was sometimes errors coming from web service side with HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

May be that should be the connection (or) unsuccessful parsing.You can check that by keeping
if(xmlParser parse)
{
blahblahblah
}
else
{
unsuccesful parsing
}